# Fastest way to Read & Parse (100,000 xml files with total size 6GB) in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am working on some project, in which i want to read and Parse 100000+ files with 6GB of size.

My Problem:
1> Read and Parse One XML File (sizes between 5kb-500kb) in few seconds.
so the complete set of XML Files (100000+ files with 6GB size) read & Parse in 3-5 Hours.
2> Fastest way to do this

Currently One XML files (5KB-500KB) take a minute of less to read and Parse.

Regards,
Mian

---

P.S. Please also review Code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><style    type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
color: #CCCCCC;
}
body {
background-color: #000066;
}
-->
</style></HEAD>
</BODY>
<script>
<!--

/*
Auto Refresh Page with Time script By JavaScript Kit (javascriptkit.com) Over 200+ free scripts here!
*/

//enter refresh time in "minutes:seconds" Minutes should range from 0 to inifinity.    Seconds should range from 0 to 59

var limit="00:10"

if (document.images){
var parselimit=limit.split(":")
parselimit=parselimit[0]*60+parselimit[1]*1
}
function beginrefresh(){
if (!document.images)
return
if (parselimit==1)
window.location.reload()
else{ 
parselimit-=1
curmin=Math.floor(parselimit/60)
cursec=parselimit%60
if (curmin!=0)
curtime=curmin+" minutes and "+cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
else
curtime=cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
window.status=curtime
setTimeout("beginrefresh()",1000)
}
}

window.onload=beginrefresh
//-->
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>


<?php

require("MagicParser.php");

//header("Content-Type: text/plain");



$dbServer = "127.0.0.1";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbName = "GDatabase";

$text = '';

$c = mysql_connect($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die("Couldn't connect to database");
$d = mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("Couldn't select database");

//mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

//mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");


$sql = "select 
id, file_name
from 
tableP_files
where status = '' limit 1";



$result = mysql_query($sql,$c);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$id = $row['id'];
$file_name = $row['file_name'];

$url = 'http://localhost/GDatabase/XML/' . $file_name;
}



$formatString = MagicParser_getFormat($url);

$update_query = "update tableP_files set format_string = '$formatString' where id =  $id";
if(!mysql_query($update_query,$c))
{
echo 'ERROR';
}
print "Format String: ".$formatString."\n\n";

// MagicParser_parse($url,"myRecordHandler",$formatString);
//  MagicParser_parse($url,"myRecordHandler","xml|ARTICLE/FLOATS-WRAP/TABLE-WRAP/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD/");
MagicParser_parse($url,"myRecordHandler","xml|ARTICLE/");

function myRecordHandler($record)
{



$dbServer = "127.0.0.1";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbName = "GDatabase";


$c = mysql_connect($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die("Couldn't connect to database");
$d = mysql_select_db($dbName) or die("Couldn't select database");

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");



$sql = "select 
id, file_name
from 
tableP_files
where status = '' limit 1";


$result = mysql_query($sql,$c);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$id = $row['id'];
$file_name = $row['file_name'];

$file_name = 'http://localhost/GDatabase/test/' . $file_name;
}


foreach($record as $key => $value)
{
    $tag =  addslashes($key);
    $value = addslashes($value);


$insert_query = "insert into tableP_xml set file_id = '$id', file_name = '$file_name', tag = '$tag', value = '$value', status = ''";
if(!mysql_query($insert_query,$c))
{
echo 'ERROR';
}




}

$update_query = "update tableP_files set status = 'done' where id = $id";
if(!mysql_query($update_query,$c))
{
echo 'ERROR';
}

echo "Done: " . $id . " - " . $file_name;
return TRUE;
}

?> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I don't think that you can parse 6GB within seconds (unless you have super computer). Try use CLI to get pass some php limitations (like timeout limit).

Comment: Thank you @Justinas for your reply. I revise my question.

Answer (score 1):

I just created 100000 xml files of size 60kb each and in a php tried to just read them with file_get_contents and it took 87.5 seconds. Mind you! I am on an ssd, have plenty of ram and a powerful i5 4th gen processor. It took ~90 seconds to just load it in memory.

So, how do you make this faster? concurrency.

I split the task into 4 chunks of 25000xml files and the time to load the files to memory (sequentially) dropped to ~30 seconds. Again, this is just the time to load the xml into memory. So if you are going to do more processing on the xml, you need more processing power or time.

Now, how do you scale this? Enter [gearman](http://php.net/gearman). Gearman lets you process parallel tasks by handing out jobs to workers via a central server. You can even have a bunch of workers on different servers register for doing your tasks. I don't think you need a super computer at all. You just need to define all your jobs once and let the workers do the jobs(asynchronously?).

Comment: Thank you @Prasanth for your reply. I revise my question.